# Detecting $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] equivalent for proxy server using PHP

Tags: php

At the moment I am testing an idea. What I want to do is display extra content on a webpage if the person visiting comes from a designated location.

I was able to make the code work using 'HTTP_REFERER' – Though this only works from websites and in this instance I want to detect whether the browser / person came from an Intranet which is behind a proxy server that is stripping out any referrer information.

Below is my current code. 
I am searching for a viable option / equivalent. 
Any thoughts would be very much appreciated.

```
<?php

$content = "hello world";

$referrer =  $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$explodestring =  explode('/',$referrer);
$explodestring = $explodestring['2'];

if ($explodestring == "www.domain.com") { 
echo $content; 
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find that in `$_SERVER['X-Forwarded-For']`.

Comment: yes (+1), but unreliable because the proxy will likely not send the header. (unless self-configured)..

Comment: Yeah, just like `HTTP_REFERER` this is not very reliable

Comment: They are for 2 different things: referrer is for the site that sent the visitor to your script and it is set by the browser, while x-forwarded-for is set by the proxy and represents the visitor's IP address